# using regex to trim off last few digits

Tags: .net

Using regex. trying to get only the last x digits of the number and 0 padding where necessary

Consider the following input

```
1234
123
12
1
```

EDIT: These will appear individually as string values

i'm trying to make a regex expression (or several regex expressions, ideally just a single)
yield

```
34
23
12
01
```

I'm a bit new to regex and backreferencing and still fumbling around a bit. any ideas on where to look or what could do this?

thanks

EDIT For clarification:
To be used in .net's System.Text.Regex.Replace() function
any of these values may come in as the input parameter.

EDIT: Thanks for the ideas everyone. It seems this cannot be done within regex. Sad as it is.

Comment: this will go up against .net's regex processor. 
i'm really just looking for a regular expression Regex.Replace to perform this.

Comment: Is using regular expressions a requirement? It would be easier if it were not.

Comment: @Mark Byers: actually probably not. my framework already supports regex.replace heavily so i thought it'd be useful to exploit this for 0 padding. it's beginning to look like i need to write in zero-padding using a different technique though.

Comment: `printf("%02d", atoi(theInput) % 100);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use regular expressions this can be done if you use a MatchEvaluator, but it would be better not to use regular expressions for this task.

Since you indicated that a solution that does not use regular expressions might be acceptable, here is one way to do it in C# that doesn't use regular expressions:

```
void Run()
{
    string s ="1234";
    s = lastXDigits(s, 3);
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

string lastXDigits(string s, int x)
{
    if (s.Length < x)
    {
        return s.PadLeft(x, '0');
    }
    else
    {
        return s.Substring(s.Length - x);
    }
}
```

Result for each of your inputs:

```
234
123
012
001
```

Comment: I think you need \d{0,x} or you'll miss anything with fewer than x digits.

Comment: @cape1232: I didn't see the requirement that the padding should be variable. I'll update.

Comment: I think i'm going to use this approach. seems i can't really do what i want with regex alone.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your other questions, I'm assuming that you're using VB.Net.

You don't need a regex; you can just use string manipulation:

```
Dim str As String

If str.Length > 2 Then str = str.Substring(str.Length - 2)
str = str.PadLeft(2, '0'c)
```

Comment: +1 for non-regex approach (turns out that it was not a requirement after all).

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to use a `.substring(int start, int length)` and then format the string to be 2 characters long, but unless you specify the language, our hands are a bit tied.

Answer (score 0):

This won't pad the zero, but seems to work (tested in JavaScript):

```
/[0-9]{1,2}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using? .. This might be easier without regex.

For example heres how you can do it in PHP:

```
$arr = array(1234,123,12,1);

foreach($arr as $num)
{
    echo '<br />'.str_pad(substr($num,-2), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```